# How to keep selected check boxes after refresh the page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, kendo-treeview

I want to keep the selected check boxes after refresh the page. Anyone has some opinions about that?

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEdDI.png)

Because when I select the check boxes then submit it, after refresh, all checked boxes are back to unchecked.

> AJAX

```
    //AJAX call for button
    $("#primaryTextButton").kendoButton();
    var button = $("#primaryTextButton").data("kendoButton");
    button.bind("click", function(e) {

    var test = $("#dropdown").val()

    $.ajax({
        url: "../DesignationProgramTemplate/getTemplate.php",
        type: "post",
            data: {'id':test,'progid':array},
                success: function () {
                // you will get response from your php page (what you echo or print)                 
                    kendo.alert('Success'); // alert notification
                    //refresh
                    //location.reload("http://hq-global.winx.ehors.com:9280/ehors/HumanResource/EmployeeManagement/DesignationProgramTemplate/template.php");
                },
        });
    });
```

> Check for check boxes

```
function checkedNodeIds(nodes, checkedNodes) {
  for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    if (nodes[i].checked) {
      //checkedNodes.push(nodes[i].moduleID);
     // checkedNodes.push(nodes[i].groupID);
      checkedNodes.push(nodes[i].id);
    }

    if (nodes[i].hasChildren) {
      checkedNodeIds(nodes[i].children.view(), checkedNodes);
    }
  }

}

var array = [];
function onCheck() {
  var checkedNodes  = [],treeView = $("#AccountingTree").data("kendoTreeView"),message;
  var checkedNodes2 = [],treeView2 = $("#AdminSystemTree").data("kendoTreeView"),message;
  var checkedNodes3 = [],treeView3 = $("#FnBTree").data("kendoTreeView"),message;
  var checkedNodes4 = [],treeView4 = $("#HumanResourceTree").data("kendoTreeView"),message;
  var checkedNodes5 = [],treeView5 = $("#InventoryManagementTree").data("kendoTreeView"),message;
  var checkedNodes6 = [],treeView6 = $("#SalesMarketingTree").data("kendoTreeView"),message;

  checkedNodeIds(treeView.dataSource.view(), checkedNodes);
  checkedNodeIds(treeView2.dataSource.view(), checkedNodes);
  checkedNodeIds(treeView3.dataSource.view(), checkedNodes);
  checkedNodeIds(treeView4.dataSource.view(), checkedNodes);
  checkedNodeIds(treeView5.dataSource.view(), checkedNodes);
  checkedNodeIds(treeView6.dataSource.view(), checkedNodes);

  if (checkedNodes.length > 0) {

    message = checkedNodes.filter(x => !!x).join(",");

    array = checkedNodes.filter(x => !!x);
  } else {
    message = "No nodes checked.";
  }
}
```

> PHP for getTemplate.php

```
$employeeID = $_SESSION['employeeID'];
$propertyID = $_SESSION['propertyID'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
$progid = $_POST['progid'];

//delete code
$positionTemplateID = $ehorsObj->EHORS_PK("tblHrsPositionProgramTemplate"); 
$sqlDelete = "DELETE IFROM tblHrsPositionProgramTemplate  
                WHERE positionTemplateID = '" . $positionTemplateID . "' 
                AND propertyID = '" . $propertyID . "' 
                AND employeeID = '" . $employeeID . "'";    
$ehorsObj->ExecuteData($sqlDelete, $ehorsObj->DEFAULT_PDO_CONNECTIONS);

for($x=0; $x< sizeof($progid); $x++ )
{
    $array = array();   

$positionTemplateID = $ehorsObj->EHORS_PK("tblHrsPositionProgramTemplate"); 
$sqlAdd = "INSERT INTO tblHrsPositionProgramTemplate 
            SET positionTemplateID = '" . $positionTemplateID . "',
            programID = '" . $progid[$x] . "',
            hrsPositionID  = '" . $id . "',
            propertyID   = '" . $propertyID . "',
            employeeID  = '" . $employeeID . "',
            dateTimeEmployee = NOW() ";     

$ehorsObj->ExecuteData($sqlAdd, $ehorsObj->DEFAULT_PDO_CONNECTIONS);

$positionTemplateIDLog = $ehorsObj->EHORS_PK("tblHrsPositionProgramTemplateLog");   
$sqlAddLog = "INSERT INTO tblHrsPositionProgramTemplateLog 
            SET positionTemplateIDLog = '" . $positionTemplateIDLog . "',
            positionTemplateID = '" . $positionTemplateID . "',
            programID = '" . $progid[$x] . "',
            hrsPositionID  = '" . $id . "',
            propertyID   = '" . $propertyID . "',
            employeeID  = '" . $employeeID . "',
            dateTimeEmployee = NOW() ";     

$ehorsObj->ExecuteData($sqlAddLog, $ehorsObj->DEFAULT_PDO_CONNECTIONS);
    }
```

This is my getTemplate.php for to get the data

Comment: Your `$.ajax()` call looks okay at first glance. Seems like you are hoping to submit the selected array of checkboxes to the php script at `../DesignationProgramTemplate/getTemplate.php` ajax. We have no idea what code you have there in order to store the data, or how you hope to recall that data when you refresh the page. Can you share the relevant php code?

Comment: I've added the getTemplate.php at above.

Comment: Yes, I want to recall the data when refresh the page

Comment: Looks like you always add a new record into the database instead of updating or deleting old records if they exist. If you check a few boxes and submit the request, can you look at the `tblHrsPositionProgramTemplate` table in the database and see that your ajax request has resulted in the creation of a new row?

Comment: Yes, it has create the new row. Exactly, what you say this- updating or deleting old records if they exist is what my boss want me to do it. But , I have no idea to correct it.

Comment: Do you have opinion on this problem?

Comment: Still need help on how to refresh but still got the selected check boxes.

Comment: Based on the way you are adding records, with a new row for each program id, before you execute the for loop, you could delete the existing data with a query like "DELETE FROM tblHrsPositionProgramTemplate WHERE positionTemplateID = '" . $positionTemplateID . "' AND propertyID   = '" . $propertyID . "' AND employeeID  = '" . $employeeID . "'

Comment: I've added the delete, but it still add new row for the same data at database. You can look above at PHP where I added the delete code. Is it correct?

Comment: Still not get the result

Comment: I'm still stuck on this problem. Anyone have better solution or opinion?